# Counting ordered triples that equal a sum

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let x,y,z be positive integers such that x+y+z=10. Compute the sum of all (not necessarily distinct) products of xyz for all possible ordered triplets (x,y,z).

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the sum over all non zero $x,y,z$ with $x+y+z=n$ we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum xyz = \binom{n+2}{5}.  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
We shall show this by setting a $1-1$ correspondene between $5-$sets of an $(n+2)-$set & these compositions.

Given $5-$sets of an $(n+2)-$set whose second element is $x+1$ and whose fourth element is $x+y+2$ ... then there are $x$ possible values for the first element, $y$ possible values for the third element and $z$ possibilities for the fifth element.

Comment: can you explain it in a more simpler way? I'm not even in college yet so I have no clue.

Comment: If we have (for instance) the composition $2+5+3=10$ this will contribute $2 \times 5 \times 3$ to the sum & it corresponds to $5$ element subsets of $[12]= \{1,2,\cdots,12 \}$ which of the form $\{ *_1,3,*_2,9,*_3 \}$. Now there are $2$ possible values for $*_1$, $5$ possibilities for $*_2$ and $3$ possible values $*_3$. In this way as we range over every $5$-set of $[12]$ we will also range over every composition $x+y+z=10$ ... & thus the sum will be $\binom{12}{5}$.

Comment: I'm still really confused. What would it correspond to 5 element subsets of 12? Where did 12 come from? For the form  {∗1,3,∗2,9,∗3}, where did the 3 and 9 come from? And the possibilities for each number is also kind of confusing. Sorry I can't understand things that well.

Comment: The $3$ and $9$ correspond to $x+1$ and $x+y+2$. Try an easier example ... say $x+y=5$ write out the $4$ possible $(x,y)$ values and calculate the sum of their products. Do you get $20$ ? Now list the $20$ $3-$sets of $[6]$ and see if you can set up a corresponcence between them. Hint: look at the middle elements.